# Using a DTO, what is the correct way to update a BLL property in WCF?

Tags: wcf, events, c#-4.0, properties, dto

Have now reached 74th rung of WCF Hell, wherein I am condemned to eternal DTO confusion. I am well used to a judiciously encapsulated object/property-setting mechanism like this, where some default value is set in the constructor, and the resetting of that value "dirties" the object:

```
public class SomeObject
{
    private int someValue;

    public int SomeValue
    {
        get { return someValue; }
        set 
        { 
            someValue = value; 
            // now SomeObject.IsDirty = true;
        }
    }

    public SomeObject(int someDefaultValue)
    {
        someValue = someDefaultValue;
    }
}
```

DTOs appear strongly opposed to this simple construct, I assume (but don't know) via the `DataContract` and `DataMember` decorators. When I step through, I see some calls in the stack I can't break into, but this is roughly the result:

```
[DataContract]
public class SomeObjectDTO
{
    private int someValue;

    [DataMember]
    public int SomeValue
    {
        get { return someValue; }
        set
        {
            // apparently the set is getting called by the constructor?
            someValue = value;
        }
    }

    public SomeObjectDTO(int someDefaultValue)
    {
        //apparently no one cares what I want to do here? next line won't fire
        someValue = someDefaultValue;
    }
}
```

I can see the value of the constructor parameter flow into the `set`, but I don't know how, and I don't see how to separate the mapper-constructed-default value from the user-edited-property-value-and-now-it-must-be-returned-to-the-service EDIT.

I'm sure this is a misuse of DTOs, but I can't see the correct WCF way to deal with these very basic, common cases:

- How do you separate the instantiation of a property value from the
  editing of it?
- If you have an object/DTO with, say, 50 properties, how do you know when the user changes 49 of them, and how do you send those changes back to the BLL mother object ship in a single shot?

Comment: Are the DTOs used on your OperationContracts?

Comment: Yes, that's the entire purpose for their creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lack of response on this question may have something to do with my lack of clarity asking it, but its points are important to WCF beginners, and I suspect there are very few WCF authorities here on SO... Anyway I can now answer it myself, in case anyone else is stuck where I was a month ago.

If you step through WCF operations that use WCF, it's very easy to misunderstand what's going on, unless you watch your call stack carefully. Some `SomeObjectDTO` may get constructed correctly on the server side, and you may think that call is complete... only to see it stepped through again. There is no way for MSFT to document this I suppose, but that "second" construction--which will ignore any constructor that uses parameters--is actually *the deserialization*. For `DataContract` beginners, I can't emphasize this enough: you will construct your object according to some rules on the service side, then it will (unless you have implemented your own serializers) 100% out of eyesight be serialized and deserialized, which on the client side results in a new, parameterless construction, meaning *you cannot construct it using anything but `set` methods*. This is because it's not being "constructed", it's being rebuilt (or, as some would say, "rehydrated") from a string of metadata about itself. It is nothing but attributes, strung together, under a parent element.

Sooo as far as the question of some `IsDirty` logic being built into a `DataMember`, forget it. The objects are transport mechanisms, throwaways, only as smart as what can be serialized, and that's pretty dumb: a list of name-value pairs. The only way to know when 1 out of 50 properties has or has not changed... is to compare values, between objects, in some smarter, (at least semi-)persisted environment: Is this what that was? No it isn't? Oh it's dirty. Times 50. Or 1000. Or however many.

What is hilarious in all of this is the notion that SOA and "decoupling" as implemented in WCF represent some giant leap forward for development. They do not; they represent a very weak consensus, a lowest-common-denominator approach that, when spun out to the individual application level, requires considerable replication of effort. Best-case scenario, that replication is expended troubleshooting federation of models, actions, and protocols; worst-case scenario, you will write *n* versions of your code to handle *n* cases. This becomes neon-visible, and therefore all the more painful, in .NET-to-.NET implementations, which is a strong argument against using WCF at all if .NET is your platform and the MSFT stack your environment. Throw in the one zillion hidden config defaults waiting to blow up an operation with zero accurate exception reporting, and you can call it a day, or three or four man-months more than you're currently scoped for.